# How to determine application up time with Gunicorn

Tags: gunicorn

I have a Flask application using Gunicorn as the web server.  I used

gunicorn -w 4

to start my application.  The application home page uses AJAX to query the application up time.  The application internally has logic to compute the up time by caching the time the application was first launched with the NOW time in the internal memory.  All is well when I used the Flask development server.  With Gunicorn, I see that the up time keeps changing.  I believe it is because I specified 4 workers.  Questions

1) Does it mean each worker may start the application separately?  How come Gunicorn does not cache the application in the memory and just forwards HTTP requests to it?

2) How to implement application up time if that is the case (i.e. as said in 1) ).

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Alex, you will be hitting a different worker, also the workers may reload. How do you plan to scale this uptime? You would need to query the supervisor (upstart, supervisord, systemd) for this information probably.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  In the past, CGI program was started everytime there was a connection.  This seemed to be not scalable and eventually, the web framework loads the program in memory.  In this case, it seems like we are going back to the CGI age (i.e. gunicorn worker starting flask app in each connection)?  Also, when does the worker decide to reload?